# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que al cambiar el estado de radiobutton se muestra la otra gráfica?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, matplotlib, radiobutton

Tengo un problema con mi programa, tengo dos funciones que da una gráfica diferente, las gráficas se plotean con Matplotlib y son añadidas a una ventana Tkinter.

Para ello uso Radiobutton, que cuando pulse uno me muestra una gráfica y cuando cambie al otro, la otra. Sucede que cuando pulso uno de ellos se muestra la gráfica bien pero cuando pulso el otro no me muestra esa gráfica, se queda en la primera.

¿Como puedo hacer que cuando en la pantalla se muestre una gráfica y yo cambie de estado el radiobutton se muestre la siguiente?. El código es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def CorrienteVsPar():

    frame2 = Frame(root)
    frame2.config(width = 800, height = 450)
    frame2.pack(side = "right", anchor = "n")

    fig1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi= 72)
    fig1.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master = frame2)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    r1 = float(Rstator.get())
    x1 = float(Xstator.get())
    xm = float(Xnucleo.get())
    r2 = float(Rrotor.get())
    x2 = float(Xrotor.get())

    jx2 = (x2*1j)

    voltaje_fase = 460/math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo = 1800

    #Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.

    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm /math.sqrt(r1**2 + (x1 + xm)**2))

    zth = ((xm*1j)*(r1 + x1*1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm)*1j)
    rth = zth.real
    xth = zth.imag

    s = np.arange(0.001, 1, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s)*n_sincronismo

    #Calculamos la caracteristica corriente vs velocidad.

    I2 = (vth) / ((rth + (r2/s)) + (xth + jx2))

    ax0 = fig1.add_axes( (0.25, .25, .50, .50), facecolor=(.75,.75,.75), 
frameon = False)
    ax0.set_title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
    ax0.patch.set_visible(False)
    ax0.plot(nm, I2)
    ax0.grid(True)

def TorqueVSPar():

    frame2 = Frame(root)
    frame2.config(width = 800, height = 450)
    frame2.pack(side = "right", anchor = "n")

    fig1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi= 72)
    fig1.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master = frame2)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    r1 = float(Rstator.get()) #resistencia del estator.
    x1 = float(Xstator.get()) #reactancia del estator. 
    xm = float(Xnucleo.get()) #reactancia del circuito tanque.
    r2 = float(Rrotor.get())  #resistencia del rotor.
    x2 = float(Xrotor.get())  #reactancia del rotor

    n_sincronismo = 1800
    voltaje_fase = 460/math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

    #Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.

    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm /math.sqrt(r1**2 + (x1 + xm)**2))
    zth = ((xm*1j)*(r1 + x1*1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm)*1j)
    rth = zth.real
    xth = zth.imag
    s = np.arange(-1.0 ,1.5, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s)*n_sincronismo

    #Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.

    torque = ((3*vth**2*r2)/s) / (n_sincronismo_rad*((rth + (r2)/s)**2 + 
(xth + x2)**2))

    ax0 = fig1.add_axes( (0.25, .25, .50, .50), facecolor=(.75,.75,.75), 
frameon = False)
    ax0.set_title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
    ax0.patch.set_visible(False)
    ax0.plot(nm, torque, linewidth= 1, color='r')    
    ax0.grid(True)

root = Tk()
root.title("ANALISIS DEL MOTOR DE INDUCCION EN REGIMEN PERMANENTE")
root.geometry('1000x600+120+40')

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.config(width = 260, height = 600, bg = "red")
frame1.pack(side = "left")

selec = IntVar()

LabelTitle = Label(frame1, text = "PARAMETROS DEL MOTOR")
LabelTitle.place(x = 55, y = 20)

#----------Datos sobre la resistencia del estator----------#

labelstator = Label(frame1, text = "R1:")
labelstator.place(x = 2, y = 70)
Rstator = Entry(frame1)
Rstator.place(x = 32, y = 70)

#----------Datos sobre la reactancia del estator----------#

labelstator = Label(frame1, text = "X1:")
labelstator.place(x = 2, y = 100)
Xstator = Entry(frame1)
Xstator.place(x = 32, y = 100)

#----------Datos sobre el entrehierro del motor----------#

labelnucleo = Label(frame1, text = "Xm:")
labelnucleo.place(x = 2, y = 150)
Xnucleo = Entry(frame1)
Xnucleo.place(x = 32, y = 150)

#----------Datos sobre la reactancia del rotor----------#

labelrotor = Label(frame1, text = "X2:")
labelrotor.place(x = 2, y = 200)
Xrotor = Entry(frame1)
Xrotor.place(x = 32, y = 200)

#----------Datos sobre la resistencia del estator----------#

labelstator = Label(frame1, text = "R2:")
labelstator.place(x = 2, y = 230)
Rrotor = Entry(frame1)
Rrotor.place(x = 32, y = 230)

#---------------------------------------------------------

radiobuton1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "grafica del torque", value = 1, 
                      variable =  selec,
                      command = lambda:(TorqueVSPar()))
radiobuton1.place(x=130,y=360)

radiobuton1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text ="grafica de corriente", value = 2, 
                      variable =  selec,
                      command = lambda:(CorrienteVsPar()))
radiobuton1.place(x=130,y=460)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Debes proveer un [MRE] si deseas ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por responder, primeramente. La razón por la cual no agregue el código es por que es bastante extenso, dude si poner solo las dos funciones y los radiobutton

Comment: Yo no te he pedido que coloques el código de tu proyecto(pareces que no has leido el enlace). Si tu proyecto es pequeño y orientado solo al problema entonces es un MRE válido, pero si al contrario tu proyecto es extenso entonces debes crear un nuevo proyecto orientado solo a implementar la funcionalidad que esta fallando y ese sería el MRE, obviamente lo último involucra esfuerzo y tiempo pero eso es lo mínimo que espera la comunidad de ti. Conclusión: tomate el tiempo para proveer un MRE si deseas ayuda.

Comment: Lo acabo de leer, perdón no me percate. Modificare para mostrar el código y sus funciones, debo crear un nuevo hilo o puedo editar este?

Comment: Solo tienes que editar la pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask], [answer] y pasar el [tour] si no lo has hecho para que conozcas las reglas de SO.

Comment: Listo amigo, muchas gracias por tus indicaciones, soy nuevo en este mundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que estas creando otro widget en vez de reusar el que ya existe.

He reescrito tu código para separar la GUI y de las otras operaciones desacoplando las partes. Ademas he escrito una clase cuya unica tarea es crear la GUI y llamar a las otras partes del proyecto.

```py
import math

from tkinter import Tk, Frame, IntVar, Label, Entry, Radiobutton

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


def corriente_vs_par(r1, x1, xm, r2, x2):
    jx2 = x2 * 1j
    voltaje_fase = 460 / math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo = 1800
    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm / math.sqrt(r1 ** 2 + (x1 + xm) ** 2))
    zth = ((xm * 1j) * (r1 + x1 * 1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm) * 1j)
    rth, xth = zth.real, zth.imag
    s = np.arange(0.001, 1, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s) * n_sincronismo
    I2 = (vth) / ((rth + (r2 / s)) + (xth + jx2))
    return nm, I2


def torque_vs_par(r1, x1, xm, r2, x2):
    n_sincronismo = 1800
    voltaje_fase = 460 / math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

    # Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.

    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm / math.sqrt(r1 ** 2 + (x1 + xm) ** 2))
    zth = ((xm * 1j) * (r1 + x1 * 1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm) * 1j)
    rth = zth.real
    xth = zth.imag
    s = np.arange(-1.0, 1.5, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s) * n_sincronismo

    # Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.

    torque = ((3 * vth ** 2 * r2) / s) / (
        n_sincronismo_rad * ((rth + (r2) / s) ** 2 + (xth + x2) ** 2)
    )

    return nm, torque


class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("ANALISIS DEL MOTOR DE INDUCCION EN REGIMEN PERMANENTE")
        self.geometry("1000x600+120+40")

        self.selec = IntVar()

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.config(width=260, height=600, bg="red")
        frame1.pack(side="left")

        Label(frame1, text="PARAMETROS DEL MOTOR").place(x=55, y=20)

        Label(frame1, text="R1:").place(x=2, y=70)

        self.r_stator = Entry(frame1)
        self.r_stator.place(x=32, y=70)

        Label(frame1, text="X1:").place(x=2, y=100)

        self.x_stator = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_stator.place(x=32, y=100)

        Label(frame1, text="Xm:").place(x=2, y=150)

        self.x_nucleo = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_nucleo.place(x=32, y=150)

        Label(frame1, text="X2:").place(x=2, y=200)

        self.x_rotor = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_rotor.place(x=32, y=200)

        Label(frame1, text="R2:").place(x=2, y=230)

        self.r_rotor = Entry(frame1)
        self.r_rotor.place(x=32, y=230)

        torque_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame1,
            text="grafica del torque",
            value=1,
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )

        torque_radiobuton.place(x=130, y=360)

        corriente_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame1,
            text="grafica de corriente",
            value=2,
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )
        corriente_radiobuton.place(x=130, y=460)

        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.config(width=800, height=450)
        frame2.pack(side="right", anchor="n")

        fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi=72)
        fig.patch.set_facecolor("xkcd:white")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ax0 = fig.add_axes(
            (0.25, 0.25, 0.50, 0.50), facecolor=(0.75, 0.75, 0.75), frameon=False
        )

    def select_plot(self):
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        value = self.selec.get()

        r1 = float(self.r_stator.get())  # resistencia del estator.
        x1 = float(self.x_stator.get())  # reactancia del estator.
        xm = float(self.x_nucleo.get())  # reactancia del circuito tanque
        r2 = float(self.r_rotor.get())  # resistencia del rotor.
        x2 = float(self.x_rotor.get())  # reactancia del rotor

        self.ax0.clear()
        self.ax0.patch.set_visible(False)
        self.ax0.grid(True)

        if value == 1:
            x, y = corriente_vs_par(r1, x1, xm, r2, x2)
            self.ax0.set_title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y)
            self.canvas.draw()

        elif value == 2:
            x, y = torque_vs_par(r1, x1, xm, r2, x2)
            self.ax0.set_title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color="r")
            self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Gui()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, reconozco que mi conocimiento es poco y al ver el código con clases pues ya es totalmente diferente a lo que estaba haciendo, le echare un ojo para tratar de entenderlo pero funciona a la perfección. Un gran saludo.